# "term does not evaluate to a function taking ..." in a global object

Tags: c++, debugging, include, global-variables

I think this problem is a bit beyond me. I'd appreciate any help.

In **UIM_Commander.cpp**, I need to use a (static) method from the class `UIM_Parser`. So, in **UIM_Commander.h**, I included **UIM_Parser.h**, like so:

```
#ifndef UIM_Commander_h
#define UIM_Commander_h

#include "..\sysm\SYSM.h"
#include "..\storm\STORM.h"
#include "..\ssqlm\SSQLM.h"
#include "..\inxm\INXM.h"
#include "UIM_Parser.h"

class UIM_Commander
{
 .....
};

#endif
```

However, this leads to this error:

> Error 8   error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments c:\workspace\sirenbase\sirenbase\uim\uim_main.cpp  3

**UIM_Main.cpp**:

```
#include "UIM_Main.h"

UIM_Commander commandCentre = UIM_Commander();    // <-- ERROR term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments 
list<string> stash;

int normal(int argc, char *argv[])
{
.....
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
.....   
}
```

Naturally, I checked in **UIM_Main.h** but it seems **UIM_Commander.h** is already included there:

```
#ifndef UIM_Main_h
#define UIM_Main_h

#define NORMAL_MODE true //set this to false to run testmain

#include "..\storm\STORM.h"
#include "UIM_Commander.h"
#include "UIM_tokens.h"
#include "UIM_Parser.h"
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
int normal(int argc, char *argv[]);

#endif
```

The global, `commandCentre`, is only used in **UIM_Parser.cpp**, so I had it as an extern in **UIM_Parser.h**:

```
#ifndef UIM_Parser_h
#define UIM_Parser_h

#include "UIM_Commander.h"
#include "UIM_Main.h"
#include "..\storm\STORM.h"
#include "UIM_tokens.h"
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

extern UIM_Commander commandCentre;    // <-- ALTERNATE ERROR missing ';' before identifier 'commandCentre'
                                       //see below
extern list<string> stash;

class UIM_Parser
{
.....
};

#endif
```

If it helps any, changing the order in **UIM_Main.h** to

```
#include "UIM_tokens.h"
#include "UIM_Parser.h"
#include "UIM_Commander.h"
```

changes the error to

> Error  1   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'commandCentre'   c:\workspace\sirenbase\sirenbase\uim\uim_parser.h   13

So, what am I doing wrong? Is this some sort of weird cyclic definition that the inclusion guards can't save me from?

---

*EDIT:*

Using `UIM_Commander commandCentre;` changes the error to

> `Error    7   error C2086: 'int commandCentre' : redefinition c:\workspace\sirenbase\sirenbase\uim\uim_main.cpp   3

if  `#include "UIM_Commander.h"` is before `#include "UIM_Parser.h"` in **UIM_main.h**. If `#include "UIM_Parser.h"` is before `#include "UIM_Commander.h"`, then the error stays

> Error 1   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'commandCentre'   c:\workspace\sirenbase\sirenbase\uim\uim_parser.h   13

---

*EDIT AGAIN*: I solved it thanks to StevieG's answer. Now **UIM_Parser.h** looks like this:

```
#ifndef UIM_Parser_h
#define UIM_Parser_h

#include "UIM_Main.h"
#include "..\storm\STORM.h"
#include "UIM_tokens.h"
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class UIM_Commander;

extern UIM_Commander commandCentre;
extern list<string> stash;

class UIM_Parser
{
.....
};

#endif
```

Pretty neat, huh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could forward declare UIM_Commander in UIM_Parser.h, and keep your includes together..

Answer (score 0):

*Edit:* Sorry, old answer was BS.

Just say:

```
UIM_Commander commandCentre;
```

The point of the **default** constructor is that it's invoked by default, so you don't need to specify it. But even if you had a non-default constructor, what you did is inefficient; don't use the copy constructor but construct directly:

```
Foo x = Foo(1,2,3); // silly copy!
Foo x(1,2,3);       // direct.
```

Comment: Hi, when I try this, the error is different but the code still doesn't compile. I edited my question with more information.

Comment: Are you sure all your `class` and `struct` constructs are terminated with a semicolon?

Comment: Yes. The problem was a cyclic dependency. I think it's solved now. I'm adding an answer myself. Thanks anyway Kerrek!

Answer (score 0):

A good friend of mine solved this, I'm the one adding the answer here because he doesn't want to.

The problem is that **UIM_Parser.h** needs **UIM_Commander.h** to know what `UIM_Commander` is. At the same time, **UIM_Commander.cpp** needs **UIM_Parser.h** to be able to call its methods.

The solution is, in **UIM_Commander.h**, to move `#include "UIM_Parser.h"` at the end of the file, right before `#endif`, like so:

```
#ifndef UIM_Commander_h
#define UIM_Commander_h

#include "..\sysm\SYSM.h"
#include "..\storm\STORM.h"
#include "..\ssqlm\SSQLM.h"
#include "..\inxm\INXM.h"

class UIM_Commander
{
 .....
};

#include "UIM_Parser.h"

#endif
```

Alternatively, you can put `#include "UIM_Parser.h"` in the beginning of **UIM_Commander.cpp**:

```
#include "UIM_Commander.h"
#include "UIM_Parser.h"

UIM_Commander::UIM_Commander()
{
    storManager = new STORM_StorageManager();
    sysManager = new SYSM_Manager(storManager);
    sqlManager = new SSQLM_Manager(storManager);
    indManager = new INXM_IndexManager(storManager);
}

.....
```

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off forward declaring UIM_Commander in UIM_Parser.h, and keeping your includes together?

Comment: @StevieG Yes, that works too. I didn't even know you can forward declare classes. If you turn your comment into a full answer I'll accept it.